# Swift: Customize UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working with a tableView where the cells have insets and rounded corners. I want to apply the same style to the row actions. Since the customising options are kind of limited (background, style and title), is there a way to do that?

[image]

That's my code for the actions:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let removeSignal = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: translate(.delete)) { (_, indexPath) in
        self.removeSignal(atIndex: indexPath.row)
    }        
    return [removeSignal]
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution without using external frameworks? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: No really. I only needed that specific behaviour in one project. I added the files (not the Pod) of MGSwipeTableCell and that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have iOS 11, you can use `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` delegate to customise your row action:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
            print("index path of delete: \(indexPath)")
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        let swipeConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        return swipeConfig
    }
```

You can set your customised text in place of `"Delete"` inside `UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete")`

You can customise more with these properties of `UIContextualAction`:

```
deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said the only things you can change on the action are:

- backgroundColor
- style (destructive (red backgroundcolor, ...)
- title

In order to change the style of the UITableViewRowAction is the probable solution is adding the image using 'patternimage'.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell). It's quite easy to integrate in a swift project and covers what I needed.